# Can't open sqltie db file in VSCode

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-code

although I have installed SQLite extension on my VSCode, I can't open any db files. the app says 'the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?'
I updated SQLite extension, reinstalled it and even reinstalled VSCode but nothing changed.I opened the file with SqliteStudio, there is no problem with the file.
what's wrong with the app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 10):

When you are using a linux distro (or WSL) you will have to install SQLite before you can use the Visual Studio Code extension. On a debian based OS you can use:

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
```

I had to restart Visual Studio Code before it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After you install [SQLite extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite), in order to open your database in VS you have to press CRTL+SHIFT+P, write "SQLite", select "SQLite: Open Database", and then you choose the database you want to open (ex: "./db/mydb.sqlite"). Finally, you click there to see your database.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI6bx.jpg)

Comment: This answer isn't providing any valuable information. You're just describing the steps in which we're already using SQLite extension. This isn't fixing anything. These are the exact steps in which we fall in this issue.

Comment: did you find an answer?  Having the same problem in windows 11->VS code 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have the sqlite installed on your computer. To test this enter "sqlite3" on your terminal/cmd. If that doesn't work, follow the instructions on the [SQLite official website](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) to perform the installation.